# SharePoint Designer Workflow - Restart Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have created a workflow that on creation and update checks if an item has the Status "Archived". If it has, the workflow will pause for 7 days and check again if the item still has the status. If once again it has the status, the workflow will pause for 3 days and check again.

If I modify the item (and the Status is still "Archived") while the workflow is paused, is it possible to restart the Status verification all over again?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you create the workflow with trigger on creation and change, it will run the workflow each time you create a new item or update the current item.

So it is not possible to restart the status verification all over again based on single **change** trigger.

Comment: thank you for the answer. but can I do it with another workflow?everytime the item is changed restart the status verification and pause for 7 days again?

Comment: Even though we could trigger another 2010 platform workflow in designer workflow, there is no change trigger to start another workflow. refer to https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/how-to-start-a-sharepoint-2010-workflow-within-a-sharepoint/